# Using ImageSource In .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I'm trying to use *System.Windows.Media.ImageSource* inside of a console application that targets *netcoreapp3.1*.  Looking at the documentation from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=netcore-3.1) it looks like it's available for .NET Core 3.0 and 3.1

> Applies to NET Core 3.1 3.0

My sample code will run just fine when it's a `net472` but as soon as I change back to `netcoreapp3.1` it will fail to build.

**Demo App**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ImageSourceTesting
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            ImageSource myImage = new BitmapImage();
            Console.Write(myImage);
        }
    }
}
```

When attempting to build I see the following:

> [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: are you including the correct NPM package that is for .net core 3.1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System.Windows.Media.ImageSource is a part of WPF, so if you created console application, then you have to add WPF support in project using `UseWPF` tag like in example:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

   </Project>
```