# Cannot using System.Windows.Media.Imaging althought already PresentationCore.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a trouble that be describe like title on VS 2018. I have already resentationCore.dll in Framework folder.
Is there any solution?

This is csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{C7A303C7-40E5-4FEE-B749-87C4B8F6DD20}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Scanner</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Scanner</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Please show your `csproj` file. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831243/using-imagesource-in-net-core-3-1/59831545#59831545

Comment: Yes I see. I have update csproj file. After add <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>, the problem is still happen.

Comment: Could you paste the information of error？